# Live Streaming radio application - NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, live-streaming, internet-radio, pls-file

I have created a simple live streaming radio application. Here a .pls file is parsing for the streaming of the audio from the url . I am getting a `NullPointerException`.

Giving my logcat below :

```
02-04 04:54:54.409: E/AndroidRuntime(1603): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-04 04:54:54.409: E/AndroidRuntime(1603): Process: com.rad, PID: 1603
02-04 04:54:54.409: E/AndroidRuntime(1603): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.rad/com.rad.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-04 04:54:54.409: E/AndroidRuntime(1603):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
02-04 04:54:54.409: E/AndroidRuntime(1603):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
02-04 04:54:54.409: E/AndroidRuntime(1603):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
02-04 04:54:54.409: E/AndroidRuntime(1603):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
02-04 04:54:54.409: E/AndroidRuntime(1603):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
02-04 04:54:54.409: E/AndroidRuntime(1603):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
02-04 04:54:54.409: E/AndroidRuntime(1603):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
02-04 04:54:54.409: E/AndroidRuntime(1603):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-04 04:54:54.409: E/AndroidRuntime(1603):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
02-04 04:54:54.409: E/AndroidRuntime(1603):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
02-04 04:54:54.409: E/AndroidRuntime(1603):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
02-04 04:54:54.409: E/AndroidRuntime(1603):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-04 04:54:54.409: E/AndroidRuntime(1603): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-04 04:54:54.409: E/AndroidRuntime(1603):     at com.rad.MainActivity.initializeMediaPlayer(MainActivity.java:133)
```

Giving my mainactivity class :

```
        import java.io.IOException;
    import java.util.LinkedList;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.media.MediaPlayer;
    import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnBufferingUpdateListener;
    import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.ProgressBar;

    public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

        private ProgressBar playSeekBar;

        private Button buttonPlay;

        private Button buttonStopPlay;

        private MediaPlayer player;

        LinkedList<String> urls;

        public String mPls="//.pls uri here";

        /*StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();

        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy); */

        /** Called when the activity is first created. */
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            initializeUIElements();



            Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable(){
                @Override
                public void run() {

                     fGetPlayableUrl(mPls);
 try {
                initializeMediaPlayer();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }                   
                                 }
            });

            thread.start(); 


        } 




        private LinkedList<String> fGetPlayableUrl( String mPls) {
            GetStreamingUrl oGetStreamingUrl = new GetStreamingUrl(MainActivity.this);
            urls = oGetStreamingUrl.getStreamingUrl(mPls);
            return urls;
        }
        private void initializeUIElements() {

            playSeekBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
            playSeekBar.setMax(100);
            playSeekBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            buttonPlay = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
            buttonPlay.setOnClickListener(this);

            buttonStopPlay = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
            buttonStopPlay.setEnabled(false);
            buttonStopPlay.setOnClickListener(this);

        }

        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (v == buttonPlay) {
                startPlaying();
            } else if (v == buttonStopPlay) {
                stopPlaying();
            }
        }

        private void startPlaying() {
            buttonStopPlay.setEnabled(true);
            buttonPlay.setEnabled(false);

            playSeekBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            player.prepareAsync();
            player.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {

                public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    player.start();
                }
        });

        }

        private void stopPlaying() {
            if (player.isPlaying()) {
                player.stop();
                player.release();
                try {
                    initializeMediaPlayer();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            buttonPlay.setEnabled(true);
            buttonStopPlay.setEnabled(false);
            playSeekBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }

        private void initializeMediaPlayer() throws IOException {
            player = new MediaPlayer();
            try {
            //player=MediaPlayer.create(this,Uri.parse("http://198.27.80.37:5412/listen.pls?sid=2"));

                player.setDataSource(urls.toString());
                //player.prepareAsync();
                //player.start();

            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            player.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(new OnBufferingUpdateListener() {

                public void onBufferingUpdate(MediaPlayer mp, int percent) {
                    playSeekBar.setSecondaryProgress(percent);
                    Log.i("Buffering", "" + percent);
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPause() {
            super.onPause();
            if (player.isPlaying()) {
                player.stop();
            }
        }
    }
```

GetStreamingUrl.java

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;

public class GetStreamingUrl {

private static String LOGTAG = "GetStreamingUrl";
private Context mContext;

public GetStreamingUrl(Context context) {
    Log.i(LOGTAG, "call to constructor");
    this.mContext = context;

}

public LinkedList<String> getStreamingUrl(String url) {

    Log.i(LOGTAG, "get streaming url");
    final BufferedReader br;
    String murl = null;
    LinkedList<String> murls = null;
    try {
        URLConnection mUrl = new URL(url).openConnection();
        br = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(mUrl.getInputStream()));
        murls = new LinkedList<String>();
        while (true) {
            try {
                String line = br.readLine();

                if (line == null) {
                    break;
                }
                murl = parseLine(line);
                if (murl != null && !murl.equals("")) {
                    murls.add(murl);

                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Log.i(LOGTAG, "url to stream :" + murl);
    return murls;
}

private String parseLine(String line) {
    if (line == null) {
        return null;
    }
    String trimmed = line.trim();
    if (trimmed.indexOf("http") >= 0) {
        return trimmed.substring(trimmed.indexOf("http"));
    }
    return "";
        }
  }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception)

Comment: @BrianRoach : I have some modifications in the code but still I am getting the exception ..can you suggest the exact edit here?

Answer (score 1):

You're referencing the urls variable in your initializeMediaPlayer() method before urls is ever initialized.

Answer (score 1):

Your `LinkedList<String> urls;` is being initialized in `fGetPlayableUrl(mPls);` but you are calling `initializeMediaPlayer();` before `fGetPlayableUrl(mPls);` where you do `player.setDataSource(urls.toString());` but `urls` is still null and you are trying to get an object from it. As a result it is giving you a `NullPointerException`

Comment: Hi @Apoorv : I have edited my codes but still getting the exception ..can you suggest the exact edit in the code

Comment: Move `initializeMediaPlayer` inside the `thread` below `fGetPlayableUrl(mPls);`

Comment: I have tried that but still getting the exception !

Comment: In `player.setDataSource` you need to pass the path of your audio file but you are passing `LinkedList`. You probably want to pass a particular position from the `LinkedList`

Comment: You mean the first element in `LinkedList`? If you want the first element you can do `urls.get(0)`.

Comment: I have modified my code but now I am getting an error like error (1, -2147483648)
E/MediaPlayer(1572): error (1, -2147483648)
E/MediaPlayer(1572): start called in state 0
E/MediaPlayer(1572): error (-38, 0)
E/MediaPlayer(1572): Error (-38,0)

Comment: Hi buddy I am back ..I have tried to get the elements from Linked List , but it is not working actually. Could you please help me to get the elements using the method you suggested (urls.get(0))..

Comment: `urls.get(0)` will give you the `String` at first position. Are you sure `urls` is not empty?

Comment: urls is not empty ,could you please write a code snippet to retrieve the elements from linked list using get(position) method..

Comment: `get` method itself is used to retrieve elements from linked list. You have to pass the position from which you want to retrieve the value